# How to install biomaRt from bioconductor

Tags: biomart

I need biomaRT but it is not installing. How do I fix this?

BiocManager::install("biomaRt")
'getOption("repos")' replaces Bioconductor standard repositories, see '?repositories' for details

replacement repositories:
CRAN: https://mirror.las.iastate.edu/CRAN

Bioconductor version 3.14 (BiocManager 1.30.16), R 4.1.3 (2022-03-10)
Warning message:
package(s) not installed when version(s) same as current; use `force = TRUE` to re-install: 'biomaRt'

> 

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't look like an error.  The relevant part of the message is

> package(s) not installed when version(s) same as current; use force = TRUE to re-install: 'biomaRt'

Essentially, this is saying "You've already got the biomaRt package installed and it's the same version as in Bioconductor, so you don't need to do anything."

You should be able to load biomaRt with: `library(biomaRt)`.